# JSF RichCalendar show clean-button on popup

Tags: jsf, richfaces, facet

Hi I configure a calendar like this:

```
<rich:calendar id="captureDateAssociatedWithDateAndTime" value="#{CaseController.caseContainer.captureDate}" datePattern="dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm" enableManualInput="true" direction="auto">
<f:facet name="footer">
    <h:panelGrid columns="3" width="100%" columnClasses="fake, width100 talign">
    <h:outputText value="{selectedDateControl}" style="font-weight:bold;" />
    <h:outputText value="{timeControl}" style="font-weight:bold;" />
    <h:outputText value="{todayControl}" style="font-weight:bold;" />
</h:panelGrid>
</f:facet>
</rich:calendar>
```

Now, how to change todayControl to cleanControl. If I type cleanControl, the clean Button shows most of the time, but sometimes no calendar-footer is shown. Thanks in advance.